Finding Biconnected components(blocks) in graph using BFS
I am searching for a code (in any language) that finds biconnected components in a graph using breadth-first search. I am beginner in coding and have an assignment for this algorithm and tried to implement it but failed
I found a lot of examples that find blocks with DFS but i need to find it using BFS. Tried changing the algorithms but every time got wrong outputs.

This is interesting. Look into page 6. You might be able to implement something.

Networkx
Use biconnected_components
import networkx as nx

# Create a graph
G = nx.Graph()

# Add edges to the graph (example)
edges = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4), (4, 5)]
G.add_edges_from(edges)

# Find biconnected components
biconnected_components = list(nx.biconnected_components(G))

# Print each biconnected component
for i, component in enumerate(biconnected_components, 1):
    print(f"Biconnected component {i}: {component}")

For using BFS for this process would require a custom algorithm... yeah...

What does this have to do with finding biconnected components?
